# Insert array elements into a table JavaScript / And prevent random number repetition

Tags: javascript, html

My program: Enter 5 answers then show table with the question number, the animal, the expected answer, the submitted answer, and the result:

[image]

How my table looks like after inserting 5 answers:

[image]

Problems:

How do I make the data indent every 5 rows?
and also, how do I make the animals not repeat (i.e. how do I make the rng that picks the animal from the array not repeat so the same animal doesn't show twice)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        #result {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <title>Animal Farm</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class='container'>
            <h1>Animal Farm</h1>
            <h2>Question <span id='question-number'>1</span></h2>
            What does the <span id="animal-name">?</span> say?
            <select id='user-selection'></select>
            <button onclick='recordAnswer()'>Submit</button>


            <div id='result'>
                <table class='table'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr><th>Question</th><th>Animal</th><th>Expected</th><th>You Picked</th><th>Result</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id='result-table'>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="animal.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
"use strict"

let farm = [] // list of all animals
let currentAnimal = undefined
let theQnum = document.getElementById("question-number")
let questionNumber = 2
let stopCounter = 1
let qArr = []
let animalArr = []
let expectedArr = []
let suppliedAnswers = []
let resultArr = []
let theAnimal
farm = generateAnimalArray()
let theMin = 0
let theMax = farm.length
let theRandom = getRandomInt(theMin, theMax)
let currentSound = farm[theRandom].says
let count = 0
let dropdown = document.getElementById("user-selection")
farm.forEach(x => {
    dropdown.innerHTML = `` + dropdown.innerHTML + `` + `<option>${farm[count].says}</option>`
    count++
});
let ddVal

showQuestion()


// return a random number in the range [min,max]
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

// return an animal object
function createAnimal(name, speak) {
    return {
        type: name,
        says: speak
    }
}

// generate and return a list of animals in our program
// it is expected that the return value be stored into the "farm" variable
function generateAnimalArray() {
    let result = []
    result.push(createAnimal('dog', 'woof'))
    result.push(createAnimal('cat', 'meow'))
    result.push(createAnimal('bird', 'tweet'))
    result.push(createAnimal('mouse', 'squeek'))
    result.push(createAnimal('cow', 'moo'))
    result.push(createAnimal('duck', 'quack'))
    result.push(createAnimal('fox', 'ring-ding-ding-ding-dingeringeding'))
    return result
}

// Pick a random animal from the list, show it to the user and set the question number
function showQuestion() {
    theAnimal = document.getElementById("animal-name")
    theAnimal.innerHTML = farm[theRandom].type
}


// Get the answer, create an object with the question number, the animal type, the expected answer and the
// supplied answer and store it into the suppliedAnswer array.
// 
// If we have seen 5 questions then show the result, otherwise show the next questions
function recordAnswer() {
    ddVal = dropdown.value
    qArr.push(questionNumber - 1)
    animalArr.push(farm[theRandom].type)
    expectedArr.push(currentSound)
    suppliedAnswers.push(ddVal)
    console.log(ddVal)
    if (currentSound != ddVal) {
        resultArr.push("Wrong")
    }
    else {
        resultArr.push("Correct!")
    }

    stopCounter++
    if (stopCounter > 5) {
        window.recordAnswer = function () { return false; };
        console.log(qArr)
        console.log(animalArr)
        console.log(expectedArr)
        console.log(suppliedAnswers)
        console.log(resultArr)
        displayResult()
    }
    else {
        theRandom = getRandomInt(theMin, theMax)
        theAnimal.innerHTML = farm[theRandom].type
        theQnum.innerHTML = questionNumber++
        ddVal = dropdown.value
        currentSound = farm[theRandom].says
    }
}

// Show the values in the suppliedAnswers as a table

function displayResult() {
    let tableDisplay = document.getElementById("result-table")
    let theResult = document.getElementById("result")
    theResult.style.display = "block"
    qArr.forEach(x => {
        tableDisplay.innerHTML = tableDisplay.innerHTML + `<td>` + x + `</td>`
    })
    animalArr.forEach(x => {
        tableDisplay.innerHTML = tableDisplay.innerHTML + `<td>` + x + `</td>`
    })
    expectedArr.forEach(x => {
        tableDisplay.innerHTML = tableDisplay.innerHTML + `<td>` + x + `</td>`
    })
    suppliedAnswers.forEach(x => {
        tableDisplay.innerHTML = tableDisplay.innerHTML + `<td>` + x + `</td>`
    })
    resultArr.forEach(x => {
        tableDisplay.innerHTML = tableDisplay.innerHTML + `<td>` + x + `</td>`
    })



}

// 1. generate the farm full of animals
// 2. Create the options for the select
// 3. show the first question

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let buffer = []
    let strBuff
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        const charList = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
        const key = event.key.toLowerCase()
        if (charList.indexOf(key) === -1) return;
        buffer.push(key)
        strBuff = buffer.toString()
        if (strBuff == "h,e,l,p") {
            window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xvypmult19M', '_blank')
            buffer = []
            strBuff
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[`forEach`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp) offers a second parameter that gives you the current iteration. So, to indent every fifth item, you can do this:

```
arr.forEach((x, i) => {
    if(i % 5 == 0) tableDisplay.innerHTML += "<td style='padding-left:20px;'>" + x + "</td>";
    else tableDisplay.innerHTML += "<td>" + x + "</td>";
});
```

To prevent repetitions when picking items from an array, you should shuffle the array and then [`pop()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pop.asp) from it, refilling it if you run out of values. Here's an example of that:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var shuffledArr = randoSequence(arr);

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  if(shuffledArr.length == 0) shuffledArr = randoSequence(arr);
  console.log(shuffledArr.pop().value);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

This example shuffles the array using [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to simplify the randomness and make it more readable, so make sure this is at the top in the head tag of your html document if you want to use this code:

```
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```